# What does a parahoric subgroup do under a surjection?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups over the ring of integers $R$ of a local field $F$ with finite residue characteristic $p$. Suppose we have a surjection $\phi$ from $G(F)$ to $H(F)$, and another surjection $\bar{\phi}$ from $G(k)$ to $H(k)$. Is this enough to conclude the image of a parahoric in $G$ is a parahoric in $H$?

Comment: Do you want to ask if the image of *some* parahoric in $G$ is a parahoric in $H$, or if the image of *every* parahoric in $G$ is a parahoric in $H$?

Comment: Also, are you assuming any relation between your $\phi$ and $\overline\phi$, or just that two such maps exist?  May I assume that they come from algebraic maps, or only that they are abstract group maps?

Comment: They are algebraic maps, and both come from applying the same construction to $G$. If it matters, I only care about $G=GSp(4)$, $H=SO(5)$, and the map comes from constructing the isomorphism between $PGSp(4)$ and $SO(5)$. I think I want the parahoric for a hyperspecial point also.

Comment: So are you really just asking if a map of smooth $R$-group schemes that is a surjection on $F$-points and $k$-points is a surjection on $R$-points?  This is Hensel's lemma.  (Possibly I am missing some hypotheses on the $R$-group schemes, but, whatever hypotheses are missing, they are satisfied for the group schemes underlying parahoric subgroups.)

Comment: Incidentally, on the principle that it's nice to mention these things before they're needed so that they don't have to be looked up later, you may want to know at some point about (roughly) the converse statement.  This is discussed under the name 'étoffé' (I don't know the English translation) in BT2, §1.7.